# Cordova splasschreen resizes on loading

Tags: cordova, splash-screen, iphone-x

How to prevent cordova app splashscreen resizing on splashscreen loading?

I'm using

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.1.0" />
```

in config.xml

Another iPhones and iPads are displaying splasscreen without resizing. Only iPhoneX does it.

What might be the problem?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you find any solution by any chance ?